# Constant object cannot be passed as var parameter

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

This is the trouble code..

```
multresult := mult(mult(temp, quatview), conjugate(temp));
```

Full procedure

```
procedure TForm2.RotateCamera(var angle: Single; x: Single; y: Single; z: Single);
var
    temp, QuatView, multResult : TQuaternion;
begin
    temp.x := x * sin(Angle/2);
    temp.y := y * sin(Angle/2);
    temp.z := z * sin(Angle/2);
    temp.w := cos(Angle/2);

    quatview.x := camera1.Position.x;
    quatview.y := camera1.Position.y;
    quatview.z := camera1.Position.z;
    quatview.w := 0;

    multresult := mult(mult(temp, quatview), conjugate(temp));

    camera1.Position.x := multresult.x;
    camera1.Position.y := multresult.y;
    camera1.Position.z := multresult.z;
end;
```

mult function

```
function TForm2.mult(var A: TQuaternion; B: TQuaternion) :TQuaternion;
 var
   c : TQuaternion;
begin
  C.x := A.w*B.x + A.x*B.w + A.y*B.z - A.z*B.y;
  C.y := A.w*B.y - A.x*B.z + A.y*B.w + A.z*B.x;
  C.z := A.w*B.z + A.x*B.y - A.y*B.x + A.z*B.w;
  C.w := A.w*B.w - A.x*B.x - A.y*B.y - A.z*B.z;
result := C;
End;
```

and conjugate

```
 function TForm2.conjugate( var quat:TQuaternion) :TQuaternion;
  begin
     quat.x := -quat.x;
     quat.y := -quat.y;
     quat.z := -quat.z;
     result := quat;
  end;
```

and if needed TQuaternion

```
type
  TQuaternion = class
    x: single;
    y: single;
    z: single;
    w: single;
  end;
```

any idea why i get this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to the question you asked is that the parameters to mult should be const. You don't modify them (and you should not), so make them const. Then your code compiles.

In a similar vein, it's bad form for Conjugate to modify its input parameter. That makes the function horrid to use. Don't do that.

Consider this line:

```
multresult := mult(mult(temp, quatview), conjugate(temp) );
```

Since conjugate modifies temp, you'd better hope that the call to conjugate is made after the other use of temp. The language makes no such guarantee. So, cross your fingers!

One of the principles worth following with arithmetic code is that input parameters/operands should never be modified, and that functions always return **new** values. Follow this principle and you'll never fall into trap highlighted above. See the second part of my answer for an illustration.

However the code won't work even with these changes because you are not instantiating any instances of the TQuaternion class. Are you sure that it's not a record?

---

The real forward progress will come when you create a good quaternion type. This should be a value type since arithmetic operations are better suited to value types for a number of reasons.

In modern Delphi you want to use a record with operators. Here's a flavour of what you need, ready to extend as you need.

```
type
  TQuaternion = record
    x: single;
    y: single;
    z: single;
    w: single;
    function Conjugate: TQuaternion;
    class operator Multiply(const A, B: TQuaternion): TQuaternion;
  end;

function TQuaternion.Conjugate: TQuaternion;
begin
  Result.x := -x;
  Result.y := -y;
  Result.z := -z;
  Result.w := w;
end;

class operator TQuaternion.Multiply(const A, B: TQuaternion): TQuaternion;
begin
  Result.x := A.w*B.x + A.x*B.w + A.y*B.z - A.z*B.y;
  Result.y := A.w*B.y - A.x*B.z + A.y*B.w + A.z*B.x;
  Result.z := A.w*B.z + A.x*B.y - A.y*B.x + A.z*B.w;
  Result.w := A.w*B.w - A.x*B.x - A.y*B.y - A.z*B.z;
end;
```

With this type your multiplication call becomes:

```
 multresult := temp*quatview*temp.Conjugate;
```

You'll surely want to write more operators and helper functions for this type.

It's really important to move the arithmetic functions into this type and out of your form. Don't use your high level GUI form class to implement low level arithmetic.

One final piece of advice. Your code has repeated mis-use of var parameters. I suggest you treat var parameters as things to be avoided. Try to write code without them if possible.

Comment: Thanks, great advice. While i will try and use this again... as of now i have to find out how to use this with firemonkey camera.. as FMX has position (x,y,z) and rotateposition(x,y,z)  While all examples i could find use opengl's  look(positionx,y,z,viewx,y,z,upx,y,z)  so working figuring all this out..

Answer (score 5):

The `mult` method declares the `A` parameter as a `var` so you must pass a variable to the method in order to work, like so.

```
 multresult := mult(temp, quatview);
 multresult := mult(multresult, conjugate(temp));
```

Comment: @GlenMorse I think you declare the parameter as **var** because of a compile error if not. Try to get rid of that var and it will be fine

Comment: I think that this answer is a somewhat shallow analysis of the problem. Yes, this change will make the code compile. But you are then left with a multitude of further problems. And even then, the solution proposed here is poor because the first fault to overcome is the erroneous use of a var parameter. Which seems to be a recurring theme.