# VCL.graphics library to FMX

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have been trying to convert a unit I had, from VCL to FMX. One of the librarys I use is `VCL.Graphics` for `TpenStyle`:

```
wallstyle,pathstyle,solvedpathstyle:TPenStyle;
```

How can I convert this to be able to use in Firemonkey?

Comment: The VCL [`TPenStyle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Graphics.TPenStyle) is for setting a line style and for the same purpose there is [`TStrokeDash`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TStrokeDash) in FMX.

Comment: @Tlama perfect, how do you figure this out?  supply as answer?

Comment: I'm assuming you read this? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Converting_from_VCL_to_FireMonkey

Comment: I have, but seen nothing about this penstyle changed to strokedash.

Comment: Documentation is **always** a good place to look first

Comment: well been looking threw documentation, was hopeing tlama had a link or something to show how he found it,  as now i need to still convert `canvas.pen`  `canvas.pen.color` and `canvas.pen.width`  I assume its somewhere in teh documentation but cant seem to find it.

Comment: Hopefully my answer shows you how to get that info too. And by the way, I hope you read my quaternion answer and found it useful. Without wishing to seem like I'm blowing my own trumpet too much, I do think there was some very valuable advice in there for you, that will be of much benefit.

Comment: Please don't change the question to make it grow and grow. One question at a time please. You asked about pen style, and you have answers for that. And links to documentation for everything else.

Comment: Not closed at all. Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295482/constant-object-cannot-be-passed-as-var-parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with the documentation for [FMX.Types.TCanvas](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas). Note that it says:

> ... Specifying the type of brush, stroke, and font to use.

We recognise brush and font from VCL times, but what about stroke?

Click on the Properties link at the top of the documentation link I gave above. Notice the various properties that have stroke in their name: Stroke, StrokeCap, StrokeDash, StrokeJoin, StrokeThickness.

Also take a look at the methods by clicking on the Methods link of the TCanvas documentation page. There you will find, amongst many others: DrawRect and FillRect. The documentation for these methods tell you which properties influence the output. For DrawRect, the outline is determined by Stroke, StrokeDash etc. For FillRect, the fill is determined by the Fill property.

So, to answer your question you need to specify a value for [StrokeDash](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas.StrokeDash). More generally, the equivalent to the VCL Pen property are the Stroke properties. And the equivalent to the VCL Brush property is Fill.

I hope I've also given you some clues as to how to navigate the documentation to find out the answers to such questions for yourself.

Comment: thanks,  but whats weird is if you go http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Types.TCanvas_Properties  it does not show brush only stroke and font.  So at first i changed brush to stroke.. but after reading it seems pen is stroke, but brush is still???

Comment: ok i guess something is throwing me off i added a little edit to the top.

Comment: Look at the methods of TCanvas next. For example, DrawRect and FillRect. The documentation there tells you which properties are used for outline styling, and for fill styling.

Comment: "To customize the drawing pen, use the Strocke,"  lol spelling error :D

Comment: I would have only figured it out by perusing the code example `FMXTCanvasSaveCanvas (Delphi)` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE4/en/FMXTCanvasSaveCanvas_(Delphi)

Comment: @glen Yes indeed, I saw that. I'm not sure what's the best way to let Emba know so that they can fix it. I'd spend my time doing so. Why do Emba make it hard for us to help them?

Comment: @Sam That demo does indeed serve the purpose nicely. I think it would pay dividends to go through all the demos and get a feel for what is available there. Then when you need to know something, your brain will say, "ah, wasn't there a demo that showed that?"

Comment: ? iam just not seeing it,  cause before i could set brush one color and pen another..now i cant?  but yes this does answer my orginal question.. now off to read about the other question

Comment: You want to know how to set the color used to fill a shape. So read the docs for FillRect. The answer is right there!! It's not called Brush anymore. It's got a different name. But the docs could not be clearer!!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  lol iam an idiot.. i keep reading fill as a verb as in what they where talking about not as it was the property...  anyhow thanks again :D

Comment: Ah, good. I've tried to give you some techniques for using the docs here. I hope they prove useful. Particularly for working out which canvas properties affect output, you need to read the docs for the methods that make the output. I think that's the top tip.